# how to return `Box<dyn TraitFoo>` from a method when struct implementing `TraitFoo` contains reference?

Tags: rust

If I have a struct `Bar` that contains a reference to `X`, I can implement a method `fun` on `Bar` that returns another struct `Foo` containing same reference:

```
struct X{}

trait TraitFoo{}
struct FooImpl<'a> {
    pub reference: &'a X
}
impl<'a> TraitFoo for FooImpl<'a> {}

struct Bar<'a> {
    pub reference: &'a X
}
impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    fn fun(&self) -> Box<FooImpl> {
        Box::new(FooImpl{ reference: self.reference })
    }
}
```

However, when I try to change `fun` to return trait instead like this:

```
impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    fn fun(&self) -> Box<dyn TraitFoo> {
        Box::new(FooImpl{ reference: self.reference })
    }
}
```

I get a compilation error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:14:9
   |
12 | impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
13 |     fn fun(&self) -> Box<dyn TraitFoo> {
14 |         Box::new(FooImpl{ reference: self.reference })
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'a` must outlive `'static`
```

Why is this not allowed? Is there a different way to achieve this kind of behaviour?

Comment: Try `Box<dyn TraitFoo + 'a>`. Trait objects default to being bounded by 'static lifetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Rust that the lifetime of the value in the box is tied to the lifetime in `Bar`:

```rust
impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    fn fun(&self) -> Box<dyn TraitFoo + 'a> {
        Box::new(FooImpl { reference: self.reference })
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4939f1dce9fa55e464a643ce00f30ba1)