# borrowed value does not live long enough when using traits

Tags: rust

I have this code that compiles correctly (sorry for the size, I really couldn't find a simpler example):

```
struct Foo {}
struct FooRepository {}

trait Action {}
struct FooAction<'a> {
    repository: &'a FooRepository
}
impl<'a> Action for FooAction<'a>{}

struct ActionSelector<'a> {
    pub repository: &'a FooRepository
}
impl<'a> ActionSelector<'a> {
    fn create_action(&self) -> Result<Box<dyn Action + 'a>, String> {
        Ok(Box::new(FooAction{ repository: self.repository }))
    }
}

struct Resolver<'a> {
    pub selectors: Vec<Box<ActionSelector<'a>>>
}
impl<'a> Resolver<'a> {
    pub fn resolve(&'a self) { }
}

fn main() {
    let repository = FooRepository{};
    let resolver = Resolver{selectors: vec![
        Box::new(ActionSelector{ repository: &repository })
    ]};
    resolver.resolve();
}
```

Now when I try to move `create_action` to a trait and make `Resolver` to hold a `vec` of traits instead, the compilation fails:

```
struct Foo {}
struct FooRepository {}

trait Action {}
struct FooAction<'a> {
    repository: &'a FooRepository
}
impl<'a> Action for FooAction<'a>{}

trait Selector<'a> {
    fn create_action(&'a self) -> Result<Box<dyn Action + 'a>, String>;
}
struct ActionSelector<'a> {
    pub repository: &'a FooRepository
}
impl<'a> Selector<'a> for ActionSelector<'a> {
    fn create_action(&'a self) -> Result<Box<dyn Action + 'a>, String> {
        Ok(Box::new(FooAction{ repository: self.repository }))
    }
}

struct Resolver<'a> {
    pub selectors: Vec<Box<dyn Selector<'a> + 'a>>
}
impl<'a> Resolver<'a> {
    pub fn resolve(&'a self) { }
}

fn main() {
    let repository = FooRepository{};
    let resolver = Resolver{selectors: vec![
        Box::new(ActionSelector{ repository: &repository })
    ]};
    resolver.resolve();
}
```

and the error:

```
error[E0597]: `resolver` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:36:5
   |
33 |     let resolver = Resolver{selectors: vec![
   |         -------- binding `resolver` declared here
...
36 |     resolver.resolve();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
37 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `resolver` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `resolver` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Resolver<'_>`
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trait Selector<'a> {
    fn create_action(& self) -> Result<Box<Action>, String>;
}
```

Your trait declares a lifetime `'a` but never uses it. You don't need that lifetime. My guess is Rust can't infer the lifetime so it assumes it's `'static` and hence your local variable doesn't live as long as `'static`. Just write your trait without it and everything works.

```
trait Selector<'a> {
    fn create_action(& self) -> Result<Box<Action>, String>;
}

impl<'a> Selector for ActionSelector<'a> {
    ...
}
```

---

**Response to question edit:**

You're still tying too many lifetimes together.

```
trait Selector<'a> {
    fn create_action(&'a self) -> Result<Box<dyn Action + 'a>, String>;
}
```

This says that `self` and the `Box` must *both* satisfy the same lifetime `'a`, which is simply not true. It's far too strict. What you probably want is this.

```
trait Selector<'a> {
    fn create_action<'b>(&'b self) -> Result<Box<dyn Action + 'a>, String>;
}
```

In the abstract, the lifetime of `self` needn't be the same as `'a`, so we just create a new lifetime `'b`. You can also restrict it so that `'a` or `'b` lives longer with appropriate constraints, based on your own needs. If you don't need to constrain `'b`, you can omit the lifetime entirely and lifetime elision will figure it out for you.

```
trait Selector<'a> {
    fn create_action(&self) -> Result<Box<dyn Action + 'a>, String>;
}
```

Likewise, `Resolver` is very strict as well.

```
impl<'a> Resolver<'a> {
    pub fn resolve(&'a self) { }
}
```

You're requiring that `self` live for as long as the `Box` inside of it, which is also not necessarily a requirement.

I might suggest, instead,

```
impl<'a> Resolver<'a> {
    pub fn resolve(&self) { }
}
```

Again, you can constrain one lifetime to be longer or shorter than the other if needed, but I highly doubt they need to be the same.

On your toy example, removing the unnecessary lifetime ties allows the code to compile. Like I said, your real example may need slightly more or less strict rules about who outlives whom, but I doubt it needs *all* of the lifetimes to be `'a` at the same time.

Comment: It is a good practice to include a lifetime parameter in trait definitions when the trait methods take references as arguments or return values (this is because the reference may have a shorter lifetime than the lifetime of the trait object resulting in UB). It is better to specify that "You don't need that lifetime here".

Comment: The only reference in this trait is `&self`, which needs to last exactly as long as the the `create_action` method and no longer. I understand if we had a reference in the return value, but I don't see the benefit of tying a trait argument to `&self` in this specific case.

Comment: looks like I oversimplified the example. I need this lifetime parameter in trait because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76114434/how-to-return-boxdyn-traitfoo-from-a-method-when-struct-implementing-traitf/76114476#76114476) problem. I've updated the question (notice that `Action` is now also a trait)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo it also worked in my real example. Thanks a lot